# Tree comparison node by node

Tags: java, tree, comparison, nodes

We are looking for a build in java data structure (I am thinking some sort of tree)
that could do the following: Compare two different structures of the same type by Nodes.
So if I had **Structure A** with nodes `1` and `2`, and **Structure B** with nodes `1` when I run the comparison I would get some sort of result that says *Node 1* is in **Structure A** but not in **Structure B** (new node).

Vice-versa, if **Structure B** has nodes that are not in **Structure A**, the comparison would be able to tell me that. And when both structures have the same nodes it would be able to compare those.

Comment: What does ```Structure``` mean? Is it a domain object? It's not very clear if you want to check simply the presence of the object(in that case just flatten the trees and compare) or if the path in the tree is important.

Comment: By structure I meant to describe a Tree like Domain object. This structure would have
a parent (root node) and a set of children (a child can be a branch or a leaf).
When I compare 2 objects I would like to know the children that are in object One and not in Two
or vice-versa. And for the nodes that have the same signature (same key) I will run a field-by-field comparison

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are in a data structures Class so I would not suggest using anything that you haven't learned in class.

With that said I would suggest making you node class, and setting up a class that checks all the nodes in a tree recursively. AND set it up to search both trees.
When you are searching both trees you can print in the recursive statement about what nodes exist and what don't depending if the nodes match or not.

Just a node as well, don't compare the nodes because they have set ID's with java compare their values instead.